# Why is my private npm registry listing all public npm modules even though I didn't replicate the registry database?

Tags: node.js, couchdb

I have been setting up a private npm registry by following along these [explicit instructions for creating a private registry](http://clock.co.uk/tech-blogs/how-to-create-a-private-npmjs-repository).  However I **skipped** the replication step because my intention is to have an empty registry that will just house private modules.

Everything appears to be working, however, when I run a test command:

```
npm --registry http://localhost:5984/registry/_design/scratch/_rewrite search /^zipper
```

I get the following output that suggests to me npm is finding this public module that shouldn't exist in my private registry:

```
npm http GET http://localhost:5984/npm_registry/_design/scratch/_rewrite/-/all/since?stale=update_after&startkey=1382392304289
npm http 200 http://localhost:5984/npm_registry/_design/scratch/_rewrite/-/all/since?stale=update_after&startkey=1382392304289
NAME           DESCRIPTION                                  AUTHOR      DATE              VERSION KEYWORDS
zipper         Insanely simple zipfile creator for node.js  =rubenv     2013-05-06 11:35  0.3.0  zip compress archive libzip
zipper-insane  Insanely simple zipfile creator for node.js  =diorahman  2011-12-17 15:54  0.0.1  zip compress archive libzip
```

Furthermore, when I try to install the module from my private registry, it installs.  What's going on here?  Since I am running my own CouchDB without replicating an existing one, I expected to have no modules in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The npm client is caching package metadata and archives in a local directory, usually in `~/.npm`. When you do a search, it will ask the registry for updates only, and use the cached data to perform the search.

Unfortunately the implementation of npm cache does not support multiple registries, it always merges all data from all registries.

As a workaround, you can tell npm to use a different cache directory when talking to your private registry:

```
npm --registry http://localhost:5984/registry/etc. --cache $HOME/.npm-private
```

Comment: Interesting, this works, however, "npm cache clean" fails to clean anything out of the cache directory